# GitHub Issue while pushing existing repo

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a code in my bitbucket and now I want to push it to my github account. I am facing issue while pushing the code as it contains a file around 223 MB. Now in bitbucket we used to do shallow cloning using depth 1. So we deleted the file using git rm command but still we are not able to push the code as it is saying cannot upload file greater than 100 MB and referring to the same file again which we have already deleted. Any idea how this can be fixed. I want to retain all my commits and tags so I cannot re-initialize git and create all new repo and push code. This what i think is due to shallow cloning as full git history still contains the reference to the big file. we are doing depth 1 cloning so last commit is only coming to our local. So How can I delete the file from full history

Answer (score 0):

See, if you try above 50mb, check the files size again.

[Conditions for large files:](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files)

[Refresh Cache](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history)

Comment: I have removed file from git but still getting large file error

Comment: Refresh cache memory on git. see the link i have added.